# Calling a function from a webservice

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I'm new in webservices and I have a question about function.

**Purpose**: I need to access a function hosted on a wcf webservice but I have trouble to do it.

I want to now if it is my mistake or if it is the code behind the webservice that doensn't work. I don't have any SoapFault or PHPException, **the function should return something but does not.**

The function I need to call is: "*GetListCollaborateur_Adresse*"

*Here is my wsdl:*

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetListCollaborateur_Adresse">
     <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="Http://www.../GetListCollaborateur_Adresse" message="tns:IWcfBiings_GetListCollaborateur_Adresse_InputMessage"/>
     <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="Http://www.../GetListCollaborateur_AdresseResponse" message="tns:IWcfBiings_GetListCollaborateur_Adresse_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>

// => So it look like we have an input parameter of "IWcfBiings_GetListCollaborateur_Adresse_InputMessage" type

<wsdl:message name="IWcfBiings_GetListCollaborateur_Adresse_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetListCollaborateur_Adresse"/>
</wsdl:message>

// => and here is my element "GetListCollaborateur_Adresse"

<xs:element name="GetListCollaborateur_Adresse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So, no type for the parameter is defined in the `<xs:sequence/>` :/

And here is what `$client->__getFunctions();` return me (my SoapClient instanciation is correct).

```
Array
(
    [0] => GetListCollaborateur_AdresseResponse GetListCollaborateur_Adresse(GetListCollaborateur_Adresse $parameters)
)
```

As the "GetListCollaborateur_Adresse" seems to be an "empty type" I tried to call the function theses ways

```
$response = $client->getListFonction();
$response = $client->getListFonction(null);
$response = $client->getListFonction(array());
```

But none of them return anything.

**So my question is**:

Do I call it in right way? (It is not impossible that the webservice is "broken" but I not sur about my code neither). The `<xs:sequence/>` let me perplexe.

Any help/comment would be appreciate, thank you.

Have a good day :)

Michaël